# Vuejs dynamic routes with variable parameters

Tags: javascript, vue.js, routes, vue-router

I start with vueJs and Webpack and I want to use vue router to create routes for elements of my table.

First i have the code of my table :

```
    <table class="table table-condensed">
                <tr style="text-align:left;" v-for="data in metadata">
                    <td>{{data.id}}</td>
                    <td><router-link :to="{ name: 'mixtapesDetails'}">
                        {{data.title}}
                    </router-link></td>
                    <td><router-link :to="{ name: 'mixtapesDetails'}">
                        {{data.artist}}
                    </router-link></td>
                </tr>

        </table>
```

Then i have my Js function to get all my data :

```
export default {
  data(){
    return {
        metadata: null
    }
  },
  methods:{
    httpGet(theUrl){
    var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttp.open("GET", theUrl, false); // true for asynchronous request
    xmlHttp.send(null);
    console.log(JSON.parse(xmlHttp.responseText));
    return JSON.parse(xmlHttp.responseText);
    }
  },
  mounted(){
    this.metadata = this.httpGet("urltooJsondata");
  }
}
```

And then i have my routes in JS :

```
export default new VueRouter({
routes: [
  {
    path: '/mixtapeList',
    name: 'mixtapeList',
    component: mixtapeList
  },
{
    path: '/mixtapesDetails/:id',
    name: 'mixtapesDetails',
    component: mixtapesDetails
}
]
```

})

The objectif is that when i click on a router-link it goes to a single page with a url like this /mixtapesdetails/id. But the difficult part is that i want the id = {{this.data.id}}. 
Sorry for my english, I really need help and i don't find the solution on web.

Answer (score 2):

Use the params object to specify:

```
<router-link :to="{ name: 'mixtapesDetails', params: { id: data.id } }">
     {{data.title}}
</router-link>
```

When `id` is `1234` that should send you to `/mixtapeDetails/1234` according to your router configuration.

See https://router.vuejs.org/en/api/router-link.html

Comment: @akatakritos Maybe you can help me. Look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57836601/how-can-make-dynamyc-routes-on-the-vue-router